# Update deleted item in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a budget calculator that calculates the transactions and income and return the balance. I have a options to remove either income and transactions but when I click the buttons, it disappears but it doesn't update the balance. The balance is in one component while the button to delete the list is in another. I have no ideas where to start. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here's my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      balance: [0]
    }

  }
  getBalance = (total) => {
    console.log(total)
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      balance: [prevState.balance, total].reduce((acc, currentVal) => {
        return Number(acc) + Number(currentVal)
      }, 0)
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" >
        <div className="count">
          <h2 className="balancetitle">Your Balance</h2>
          <h1 style={{ color: this.state.balance >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}>${this.state.balance}</h1>
        </div>
        <Transactions getBalance={(total) => this.getBalance([total])} />
        <Income getBalance={(total) => this.getBalance([total])} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const Transactions = (props) => {
    const [expenses, setExpense] = useState([])
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState([])
    const [id, setId] = useState([])
    const [listOfTrans, setListofTrans] = useState([])
    const [total, setTotal] = useState([0])


    //fires on click or enter
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addExpense({
            amount,
            expenses,
            id
        });
        props.getBalance(-Math.abs(amount));
        setAmount('');
        setExpense('');

    }


    //get value of inputs
    const getValue = (hookSetter) => (e) => {
        let { value } = e.target;
        return hookSetter(value)
    }
    // turn amount and expense into objects and put them setListofTranas
    const addExpense = (expenseObject) => {
        setListofTrans([...listOfTrans, expenseObject])

    }

    // get total amount of listoftrans
    const getAmount = () => {

        if (listOfTrans.length >= 0) {
            let listAmount = listOfTrans.map(list => {
                if (list.amount) {
                    return -Math.abs(list.amount);
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            })

            return listAmount.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
                return Number(acc) + Number(currentValue)

            }, 0)
        } else return 0

    }


    //update amount total on click
    useEffect(() => {
        setTotal(getAmount())

    }, [listOfTrans])

    // delete item from array
    const deleteExpense = (i) => {
        let objExpense = i
        setListofTrans(listOfTrans.filter((list) => {
            return list.id !== objExpense
        }))
    }


    return (

        <div className="transactions">
            <div className="expenses">
                <span>{amount === '' || expenses === '' ? <p>Please Fill Out Input Fields</p> : ''}</span>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="expense"
                        className="formfield"
                        name="expense"
                        placeholder="Expense..."
                        value={expenses}
                        onChange={getValue(setExpense)}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="amount"
                        className="formfield"
                        name="amount"
                        placeholder="Amount..."
                        value={amount}
                        onChange={getValue(setAmount)}
                    />
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className="finalbalance ">
                <div className="finalexpense final">

                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Total Expenses: ${total}</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>EXPENSES</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        {
                            listOfTrans.map((trans, i) => {
                                return (
                                    <tbody key={trans.id}>
                                        <tr key={trans.id++}>
                                            <td>{trans.expenses}</td>
                                            <td>{"$" + trans.amount}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <button onClick={() => deleteExpense(trans.id)}>
                                                    <i className="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                                </button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a transaction you need to add (*or subtract, whichever is the opposite of when the expense is added*) the amount back into the overall balance.

```
const deleteExpense = (i) => {
  let objExpense = i;
  setListofTrans(
    listOfTrans.filter((list) => {
      if (list.id === objExpense) {
        props.getBalance(Math.abs(list.amount)); // <-- add the amount back to balance
        return false;
      }
      return true
    })
  );
};
```

[image: Edit update-deleted-item-in-another-component]

Just a suggestion here, but IMO it would make more sense to store the list of transactions in the parent and derive the total balance to display, and simply pass the transactions to `Transaction` to be displayed as a list. It would remove the need to keep state in two separate components in sync, leaving your app with more of a single source of truth.

Comment: Also, I was going to do that but I keep thinking you have to keep different components in different areas, that I overdo the splitting up of the components.

Comment: @Alanaj Ah, you're welcome, again! :) Sure. I think a good rule of thumb though is to not store any state anywhere that can be easily derived/computed from existing state, like totals of values over an array. Presumably the array is only rerendered when it updates, so to will the balance only update at the same time.